# Showing missing CSS file when using Content Type as ms-word in MS Word 2010

Tags: asp-classic, ms-word, content-type

In classic asp using the following code to print the document in MS Word

```
    Response.ContentType ="application/msword"
Response.AddHeader "content-disposition", "attachment; filename=report.doc"
```

it was working fine in MS Word 2007, but I'm getting the following error when open in MS Word 2010
[image]

and also not getting the format in MS Word doc.

Comment: Have you tried changing the file name from "report.doc" to "report.docx
"?

Comment: See this [stackoverflow article][1] about the correct content type to use for .docx files.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc